# How to run my Three.js application under Visual Studio?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, three.js

As you can see below, my application runs fine in my Linux server.

http://www.dealey-plaza.org/this-government-as-promised/SBT-MBT-Tools/Haags-Measurement-Tool/Pinocchio-Nose/

However, I would like to run it, and learn using Visual Studio (2017). I have found some instructions on YouTube, but they are old.

Apparently I need to attach the running code to a process? Since Google Chrome seems to be a preferred browser in the VS ecosystem, I would like to attach my code to it. Edge is fine as well. I have had many problems with Firefox. It seems that they have a world of their own.

Bottom line: any browser will do, as long as I can execute/debug my Javascript code.

See enclosed images.

[3 Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LuMi.jpg)

Comment: To be honest it is better to debug JS code in chrome/FF dev tools. It is much easier and faster, works for apps of any scale, works with webpack, typescript etc.. Some IDE's (Jetbrains WebStorm, Rider) have special plugins to help debug with browser.

Comment: It supports modules, async/await, better for complex client scenarios, integrated with html/css engine, element inspector. profiler.